# def that takes a string and returns first half lower case and second part upper

Tags: python

I'm new to python and want help cleaning up my code.

I had to make a definition that takes a string and returns the first half lowercase and second part uppercase.

This is my code - but I can't help think there's a cleaner way to write this.

```
def sillycase(string):
    x = len(string)/2
    y = round(x)
    print (string[:y].lower() + string[y:].upper())
```

Comment: Well...for starters, it's returning `None`...

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty good already, but as mentioned, it was not returning anything. How about this?

```
def sillycase(string):
    y = round(len(string)/2)
    return string[:y].lower() + string[y:].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, your current method is returning `None`.  If you're just printing values out, you're not actually `return`ing anything back to the caller.

Ultimately though, this can be cleaned up a great deal.  You don't have to bother with the concatenation if you use `format` instead.  Also, if you're dealing with integer division, it will always round down to the nearest integral - so there's no benefit in calling `round`.  The double-slash `//` operator enforces that behavior, so it'll work the same between Python versions.

```
def sillycase(s):
    half = len(s)//2
    return "{}{}".format(s[:half].lower(), s[half:].upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take it in steps. First of all, how do you return values from a function?

```
def return_True():
    return True

def return_half(x):
    return x/2
```

Second, how do you pull pieces out of a string?

```
In [1]: "abc"[:2]
Out[1]: "ab"

In [2]: "abc"[2:]
Out[2]: "c"
```

Third, how do you get a whole number from division?

```
In [1]: 5/2
Out[1]: 2.5  # 2 in Python2, but don't rely on that

In [2]: 5//2
Out[2]: 2    # in both Python2 and Python3
```

Fourth, how do you manipulate cases of a string?

```
In [1]: "TeSt".upper()
Out[1]: "TEST"

In [2]: "TeSt".lower()
Out[2]: "test"
```

Finally let's put it all together:

```
def sillycase(s):
    mid_point = len(s) // 2
    first_half = s[:midpoint]
    second_half = s[midpoint:]
    return first_half.lower() + second_half.upper()
```